# Entries of a unitary matrix

Tags: matrix-decomposition, orthonormal, quantum-computation, quantum-information, unitary-matrices

In the solution a a problem in quantum computation I saw this line:
$$U_{ij}=\langle\psi_i|\left(\sum_k|\phi_k\rangle\!\langle\psi_k|\right) |\psi_j\rangle.$$

Where $U_{ij}$ are the entries of a unitary matrix $U$ and $\phi_k$ and $\psi_k$ form two different orthonormal basis vectors.

I already succeed to prove that $U$ can be written as the sum of $\phi_k$ and $\psi_k$ vectors but I don't understand why the expression above is the entry $U_{ij}$.

Can someone help?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

That's how you define the entries of the matrix of $U$ with respect to the basis $\{\psi_j\}$. The entries of $U$ with respect to that basis are defined as the numbers that satisfy
$$
U|\psi_j\rangle=\sum_k U_{kj}|\,\psi_k\rangle.
$$
As the basis is orthonormal, you get
$$
\langle \psi_i|U|\psi_j\rangle=U_{ij}.
$$